# SDL2_ttf library not loaded on OS X

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, sdl

I'm using XCode 4.6 on OS X 10.8.

When I build my SDL2 project trying to use SDL2_ttf.framework I get this error.
I first want to make clear that I have built the SDL2.framework and I've included the framework in my project. The build seems to be OK it's more when I try to run the project.

dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL2_ttf

Having a look at the SDL2.framework I do have SDL2_ttf in Versions/A

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you added both the SDL2.framework and the SDL2_tff.framework to your project?

Comment: See these two images for info:

http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/4154/screenshot20130404at230.png
http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4154/screenshot20130404at230.png